# Codeigniter View and echo

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, echo

I  have a function that which process the side bar of a web page in codeigniter.

as follows :

```
function process_sidebar()
{
$this->load->view("first_access"); // ------------(1)
$this->load->view("second_access");// --------------(2)
echo "Here i want to show some data after loading view second_access"; //pls note here --(3)

$this->load->view("third_access"); // --------------------(4)
$this->load->view("fourth_access"); //-------------------------(5)

}
```

Please check the order numbers,but the problem is codeigniter not keeping the order.

it rendering the view last and showing the `echo` part first..

how can i overcome this ?

Thank you.

Comment: When you `echo`/`print`, you're sending that output directly to the output buffer, which is what the browser will actually see (think of it like cars lining up at a red light). In CodeIgniter views, you're telling CI to store that content and output it later within a structure. This is akin to parking the cars in a parking lot, deciding which cars will go first, then sending the cars to the light only after you've finalized the order. Just as you don't want any cars to sneak into line when you're not looking, you don't want to `echo`/`print` like that, since it's "out of order".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to `append_output()` rather than `echo`:

```
<?php
function process_sidebar()
{
    $this->load->view("first_access"); // ------------(1)
    $this->load->view("second_access");// --------------(2)
    $this->output->append_output("Here i want to show some data after loading view second_access"); //pls note here --(3)
    $this->load->view("third_access"); // --------------------(4)
    $this->load->view("fourth_access"); //-------------------------(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how view works in CodeIgniter, it doesn't get displayed immediately but gets buffered instead and displayed together later. To overcome, if the text you want to display in between is static, make it part of the 2nd or 3rd view. Otherwise, make it a variable of 2nd or 3rd view, and pass the text as view variable.

Comment: Okkey,i realized that. But can i do something like `echo $this->load->view("myview","",TRUE);` is there any performance issue while doing like this ?

Comment: yes, that's an alternative way. AFAIK, that depends on output_buffering settings in php.ini.