# Codigniter Messes Up View Order

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-2

This is not a duplicate.

Neither one of these methods work

[CodeIgniter view loading not loading in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421345/codeigniter-view-loading-not-loading-in-order)

[Codeigniter View and echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138608/codeigniter-view-and-echo)

```
  $this->load->view('includes/header');
  $this->load->view('includes/left_sidebar');


  $this->load->view('content/content');
  $this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

I've tried the 'echo' suggestion in the two links both with the second parameter as null and as array();

No matter what I do, the sidebar always loads at the bottom.

I've also tried loading these views within the content view with no luck.

I am using CodeIgniter 2.14, Any other suggestions for getting the views to load in the correct order?

There is no php functionality other than loading the includes.

Comment: I removed all the html markup and just put 1,2,3,4 in header, sidebar, content, footer respectively and everything loaded in order. Can it be the html that is throwing it off?

Comment: The sidebar loads at the bottom visually? Or in HTML order? Cause it might be a CSS issue of positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your css for sidebar. Check source code of the rendered page and see if sidebar section is at the bottom or at right place.

Comment: I had a misplaced </div>